# Error in process execution from Nolio

Tags: devops, nolio, ca-lisa

I'm new to nolio, and i've configured my first process.
After publishing it successfully i tried running the process but it failed.
The following error appeared:

"Parameter value check failed: Parameter [tar.gz] with scope [RELEASE] is missing parameter value. Process run will be stopped."

What does this error mean? what should i check?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Parameter `tar.gz` is probably defined with a `Release` scope (Other options are internal, user-input and environment). This means that if it is not set with a default value, it will only get its value in the context of a `Deployment`. If you try to run the process directly, not in the context of a deployment it would have no value and could lead for the process getting stuck or failing.

In general the process is the logic and the deployment gives it context. A deployment is a series of steps (processes) with specific values that are set to their release parameters.

If you want to use this parameter in a process that is not executed within a deployment, define it is as `internal` (or as `user-input` if you want to set it manually during execution)